# matplotlib major display issue with dense data sets

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've run into a fairly serious issue with matplotlib and Python.  I have a dense periodogram data set and want to plot it.  The issue is that when there are more data points than can be plotted on a pixel, the package does not pick the min and max to display.  This means a casual look at the plot can lead you to incorrect conclusions.

Here's an example of such a problem:
[image: example]

The dataset was plotted with `plot()` and `scatter()` overlayed.  You can see that in the dense data fields, the blue line that connects the data does not reach the actual peaks, leading a human viewer to conclude the peak at ~2.4 is the maximum, when it's really not.

If you zoom-in or force a wide viewing window, it is displayed correctly.  `rasterize` and `aa` keywords have no effect on the issue.

Is there a way to ensure that the min/max points of a `plot()` call are always rendered?  Otherwise, this needs to be addressed in an update to matplotlib.  I've never had a plotting package behave like this, and this is a pretty major issue.

Edit:

```
x = numpy.linspace(0,1,2000000)
y = numpy.random.random(x.shape)
y[1000000]=2

plot(x,y)
show()
```

Should replicate the problem.  Though it may depend on your monitor resolution.  By dragging and resizing the window, you should see the problem.  One data point should stick out a y=2, but that doesn't always display.

Comment: What version of MPL are you using?  If it is the latest you should create an issue on the github tracker (which will ensure this gets attention from the core devs).  Can you please post an example data set + code you used to generate that graph?  It makes it much easier to test.

Comment: if you use `plot(..., marker='.', linestyle='-')` does it hit the min/max properly?

Comment: @tcaswell  Added code.  The marker and linestyle changes did not help.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't replicate it... what's your backend? `matplotlib.get_backend()`

Comment: If I run the code exactly as posted, I get `OverflowError`s from the renderer.  By cutting all the numbers down by 10 I can get it to run, but can always see the spike.  What does `matplotlib.__version__` give?

Comment: can you post the _exact_ data you used to generate that graph?

Comment: I've had similar problems before, where resizing the window size or xlim/ylim changed the amount of visibility in dense regions.

Comment: @tiago Can you reproduce this now?

Comment: @tcaswell: the above code seems to crash my qt4 backend, and using the osx backend (even with 10x less points) never seems to finish. But I don't remember having the problem with recent versions of matplotlib.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the path-simplification algorithm in matplotlib.  While it's certainly not desirable in some cases, it's deliberate behavior to speed up rendering.

The simplification algorithm was changed at some point to avoid skipping "outlier" points, so newer versions of mpl don't exhibit this exact behavior (the path is still simplified, though).

If you don't want to simplify paths, then you can disable it in the rc parameters (either in your `.matplotlibrc` file or at runtime).

E.g.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['path.simplify'] = False
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However, it may make more sense to use an "envelope" style plot. As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    num = 10000
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, num)
    y = np.cos(x) + 5 * np.random.random(num)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
    ax1.plot(x, y)
    envelope_plot(x, y, winsize=40, ax=ax2)
    plt.show()

def envelope_plot(x, y, winsize, ax=None, fill='gray', color='blue'):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    # Coarsely chunk the data, discarding the last window if it's not evenly
    # divisible. (Fast and memory-efficient)
    numwin = x.size // winsize
    ywin = y[:winsize * numwin].reshape(-1, winsize)
    xwin = x[:winsize * numwin].reshape(-1, winsize)
    # Find the min, max, and mean within each window 
    ymin = ywin.min(axis=1)
    ymax = ywin.max(axis=1)
    ymean = ywin.mean(axis=1)
    xmean = xwin.mean(axis=1)

    fill_artist = ax.fill_between(xmean, ymin, ymax, color=fill, 
                                  edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5)
    line, = ax.plot(xmean, ymean, color=color, linestyle='-')
    return fill_artist, line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]